# unable to code correct foreach syntax

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking for to iterate over an arrayList which sometimes have a common head element. The arrayList is populated as follow :

```
     //getters, setters
     public static void main(String[] args) {

     ArrayList<Sports> kayak = new ArrayList<>();
     kayak.add(new Sports(sportsmanID[0], 21)
     kayak.add(new Sports(sportsmanID[0], 24)
     kayak.add(new Sports(sportsmanID[1], 29)
```

sportsmanID is declared within my main method, and is declared like this :

```
     sportsmanID = new int[20];
     // bunch of equals
```

The point would be to add the integer associated with each sportsmanID once.
See expected outcome :

```
    sportsmanID[0] = 21+24
    sportsmanID[1] = 29
```

Of course, all my variables have their respective getters and setters, otherwise i wouldn't be able to access the arrayList whatsoever.

After having tried every form of array itteration i can think of, i want to try to resolve this with an enhanced for loop. Logically, it has sense : i want that for each sportsmanID, perform a calculus. 
However, since i am dealing with an array of object, plus the fact that my syntax is terribly off, I struggle. It seems to have meaning given the OOP language that java is; but i cannot wrap my head around it.

Can anyone point me towards the good direction ? I have been stuck on this one for a while, bless anyone who shall rescue me.

best and thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give the declaration of `sportsmanID` array ?

Comment: When you say `sportsmanID[0] = 21+24` do you mean the entry should contain the ***`String`*** `"21+24"` or the value `45`?

Comment: the value, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd override `equals` and `hashcode` as follows:

```
class Sports {
    private int id;
    private int value;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Sports sports = (Sports) o;
        return id == sports.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {    
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sports{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Sports(int id, int value){
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then create a `merge` method with which you can pass a `Sports` object to along with the list. This method will then check if the object you want to add already exists in the list by `id` then simply add their values together and don't bother adding another object with the same id.

However, if it does not already exist then add the object to the list.

```
public static void merge(Sports obj, List<Sports> source){
        int index = source.indexOf(obj);
        if(index == -1) {
            source.add(obj);
            return;
        }
        Sports tempObj = source.get(index);
        tempObj.setValue(obj.getValue() + tempObj.getValue());
}
```

then simply do:

```
ArrayList<Sports> kayak = new ArrayList<>();
merge(new Sports(sportsmanID[0], 21), kayak);
merge(new Sports(sportsmanID[0], 24), kayak);
merge(new Sports(sportsmanID[1], 29), kayak);
```

`kayak` now has the following elements:

```
[Sports{id=1, value=45}, Sports{id=2, value=29}]
```

Comment: i can't thank you enough for such a complete answer. I'll take a while to process it threw, but the learning experience is worth it - and it looks sexy.

Comment: @applz you're more than welcome and glad it helped you solve your problem. feel free to post any questions you may have regarding the code. happy coding :).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Sports` looks something like the following:

```
class Sports {
    private final int sportsmanId;
    private final int someInt;


    public Sports(final int sportsmanId, final int someInt) {
        this.sportsmanId = sportsmanId;
        this.someInt = someInt;
    }

    public int getSportsmanId() {
        return sportsmanId;
    }

    public int getSomeInt() {
        return someInt;
    }
}
```

Then the following will do what you want:

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> sumBySportsmanId = kayak.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Sports::getSportsmanId, summingInt(Sports::getSomeInt)));
```

Using the following `static` imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingInt;
```

How does this work:

- `kayak.stream()` returns a `Stream<Kayak>`, giving a "stream" of the elements
- `stream.collect` takes a `Collector`, this gathers all the elements
- `Collectors.groupingBy` takes two arguments here, the first is a method reference to the item to group by. It will create a `Map<>` with the key being the grouping and the value being the result of the downstream collector
- `Sports::getSportsmanId` is a method reference that allows the `groupingBy` to group in the `sportsmanId`
- `Collectors.summingInt` is another `Collector`, this one takes some way to get an `int` from the items passed in, as the grouping lives a `Map<Integer, List<Sports>>` we need to extract the `someInt` value from the `Sports`
- `Sports::getSomeInt` is a method reference that gives the `int` to the `summingInt` `Collector`.

Comment: I managed to make it work also; thank you for the help you provided !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a `get` and `set` method so that you can retrieve the ID from each Sport, and after that, you can iterate in 2 different ways:

```
kayak.forEach(s -> //perform something here);

for (Sport s: kayak){
//perform something here
}
```

You will then use the `getId()` method to retrieve the value and do something with it

Answer (score 0):

What about `Map`

```
Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

ArrayList<Sports> kayak = new ArrayList<Sports>();
kayak.add(new Sports(sportsmanID[0], 21);
kayak.add(new Sports(sportsmanID[0], 24);
kayak.add(new Sports(sportsmanID[1], 29);

for(Sports s:kayak) {
    if(count.containsKey(s.getSportsmanID())) {
        count.put(s.getSportsmanID(), count.get(s.getSportsmanID())+s.getScore());
    } else {
        count.put(s.getSportsmanID(), s.getScore());
    }
}

System.out.println(count.get(sportsmanID[0]));
```